# Syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: command-line, batch, teamviewer

I am looking into creating a batch file that runs at startup, via GPO.

The batch is going to install TeamViewer host so we can deploy this to our end users without any input from them.

The script is designed to see if there is a file with the machine name stored locally and to stop if there is. If not, then remove every trace of Teamviewer and install the host version we have then to create a file locally to mark the correct version is installed.

When we run the script, the console gives the error 'The syntax of the command is incorrect.'

Please can any of you wizards advise where I am tripping up as I imaging that if I can run the batch file without a problem, the GPO should be able to as well.

If there is an easier or tidier way to do this, please please let me know.

When we run the script without the IF, it works without issue.

```
if exist "C:\TeamViewer15\%computername%.jmw" (exit) else (

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq TeamViewer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "TeamViewer.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (GOTO :KILL) ELSE (GOTO :REMOVEMSI)
:KILL
taskkill /f /im TeamViewer.exe
TIMEOUT 2
GOTO :REMOVEMSI
:REMOVEMSI
wmic product where vendor="TeamViewer"
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" GOTO :CHECKOS
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic product Where "vendor like 'TeamViewer'" get IdentifyingNumber /value ^| find "="') do set "id=%%f"
msiexec.exe /x "%id%" /qn
GOTO :CHECKOS
:CHECKOS
cd\
Set "OS64=C:\Program Files (x86)"
IF EXIST "%OS64%" (GOTO :UNINSTALL64) ELSE (GOTO :UNINSTALL32)
:UNINSTALL64
cd\
Set "OLD64="C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version"*"
IF EXIST "%OLD64%" (GOTO :PREVIOUS64) ELSE (GOTO :REMOVE64)
:UNINSTALL32
cd\
Set "OLD32=C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version*"
IF EXIST "%OLD32%" (GOTO :PREVIOUS32) ELSE (GOTO :REMOVE32)
:PREVIOUS32
cd\
cd %ProgramFiles%\TeamViewer\Version*
IF NOT EXIST "*uninstall*" GOTO :REMOVE32
start uninstall.exe /S 
GOTO :REMOVE32
:REMOVE32
cd\
cd %ProgramFiles%\TeamViewer
IF NOT EXIST "*uninstall*" GOTO :REMOVEFILES32
start uninstall.exe /S
GOTO :REMOVEFILES32
:REMOVEFILES32
reg delete "HKLM\Software\TeamViewer" /f
cd %temp%
rd TeamViewer /s /Q
GOTO :INSTALL
:PREVIOUS64
cd\
cd %ProgramFiles(x86)%\TeamViewer\Version*
IF NOT EXIST "*uninstall*" GOTO :REMOVE64
start uninstall.exe /S
GOTO :REMOVE64
:REMOVE64
cd\
cd %ProgramFiles(x86)%\TeamViewer
IF NOT EXIST "*uninstall*" GOTO :REMOVEFILES64
start uninstall.exe /S
GOTO :REMOVEFILES64
:REMOVEFILES64
reg delete "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer" /f
cd %temp%
rd TeamViewer /s /Q



REM INSTALL TEAM VIEWER HOST V15

start /wait msiexec.exe /i "\\DFSNAMESERVER\files\admin\Software Distribution\TeamViewer\TeamViewer_Host.msi" /qn CUSTOMCONFIGID=MYCUSTOMERCONFIGID APITOKEN=CUSTOMERAPITOKENKEY ASSIGNMENTOPTIONS="--reassign --alias %ComputerName% --grant-easy-access"



REM CREATE INSTALLATION MARKER

md C:\TeamViewer15
fsutil file createnew "C:\TeamViewer15\%computername%.jmw" 10
)



exit
```

I've changed the TeamViewer and server details for this forum (those bits work)

Many thanks
Tom

Comment: If you run it without which "if"? There are multiple in your script...

Comment: Is there a limit to the amount of IF statements that can be run in a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

At first appearance (maybe incomplete):

1. [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404) enclosed in `()` parentheses. (**line 1**): use `if exist "C:\TeamViewer15\%computername%.jmw" (exit)` instead of <strike>`if exist "C:\TeamViewer15\%computername%.jmw" (exit) else (`</strike> **and** remove corresponding closing parenthesis (**line 65**, somewhere before the `exit` keyword).
2. `start` commands (mainly in **line 61**): [Always include a *TITLE*](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) e.g as `start "" /wait msiexec.exe /i …`
3. More issues with `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in …` (**line 12**):

- the `like` operator requires a wildcard character with your WQL query, use `%%`;
- there are (wrong) inner apostrophes, Use either backticks with [`usebackq` alternate quoting style](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) instead of outer apostrophes, or use something like `Where ^(vendor like "%%TeamViewer%%"^)` (note [parentheses escaped using `^` Circumflex Accent](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)) instead of <strike>`Where "vendor like 'TeamViewer'"`</strike>;
- you could encounter the WMIC *trailing `<CR>` problem*. For solution, see Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266).